# Ubuntu 13.04 with wubi works

Tags: 13.04, wubi

I don't know if I'm the only person to find this out or not. But anyways I like the way wubi works so I was kind of mad that 13.04 didn't have it. But I was playing around, and I downloaded the Ubuntu 13.04 iso file and I extracted it to a folder, and surely enough after I extracted it, I went to that folder and in that folder I found awubi.exe so I double clicked it and it worked! Now I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 off of a wubi install and it works perfectly fine for me. This shocked me because I thought they had gotten rid of wubi installs after 12.04 but I guess it's still possible. I thought I would just share this with everybody.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Canonical stopped offering wubi because it does not work with UEFI-based PC's. If you upgraded to Windows 8 (it didn't come pre-installed), you probably have BIOS firmware, which wubi does work with. In any case, you don't really have a specific question you're asking here. Next time you want to share something like this with the community, make a question and answer it yourself with the answer box! It's a Q&A site, quite different than a forum as I learned...

Comment: It wasn't really a question it was just something I discovered and wanted to share with everybody who wants to use wubi to install Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: @RobertCross Right, next time, as I said, you can do this by answering your own question (that's the best way to share on a q/a site like this) :)